# Slow MediaExtractor seekTo

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seek

I created a video player using `MediaCodec` and `MediaExtractor`, but when I try to change the media position using `MediaExtractor` `seekTo` method it is really slow (took 10 seconds to seek for a 1080P video) while the SDK `MediaPlayer` can seek in real-time. Any idea to fix this?

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(SAMPLE);    
.
.
.
extractor.seekTo(480000000, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
```

**Update**

Theo original project is [here](https://github.com/vecio/MediaCodecDemo)

Comment: Hi, this is a question. How can you create a video player using MediaCodec and MediaExtractor? 
As I understand, these classes are in /media/jni, did you rebuild the "media-jni"?
If you did, can you guide me how to do that? My current issue is rebuilding "media-jni" (called from MediaPlayer.java), so that I can control the headers (with coookie) in setDataSource() function.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: @hami, MediaCodec and MediaExctractor are introduced in Jelly Bean and they are public (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)

Comment: Thank you for information. However, in my task I must use Android level 14 instead of JB, what's a pity.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the bug that caused the seeking to be slow. It was the sync clock used for maintaining media FPS.

I've just uploaded the new working project with the following features:

- Correct seek
- Correct media current position
- Correct media duration
- MediaController
- Playback fix for some videos that hardware decoder (MediaCodec) can't detect their frame time stamps correctly.

https://github.com/mafshin/MediaCodecDemo

Comment: Have you found a fix?

Comment: @StackOverflowed, actually I switched from MediaCodec to the well recognized library, Vitamio (https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle).